# Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием

Tags: грамматика, падежи

У ребенка в домашней работе предложение: *«…Мы отвести не в силах глаз.»*

По смыслу подразумевается множественное число, и тогда слово *«глаз»* стоит в родительном падеже множественного числа.

С другой стороны, *«отвести»* — переходный глагол, и следовательно управляет винительным падежом. Следовательно, слово «глаз» стоит в винительном падеже единственного числа.

Вот такой парадокс…

В каком падеже и числе употреблено слова *«глаз»* в этом предложении?

Comment: Раз уж заголовок сменен с частного на общий, то полагаю разумным довести дело до логического конца — закрыть вопрос как дубликат. Проголосовал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подобный вопрос уже задавался: [Direct object of negated verbs takes which case?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/2807/2060), и я сначала хотел оставить комментарий, но решил, что стоит продублировать ответ на русском.

> При переходных глаголах с отрицанием в одних случаях явно преобладает употребление родительного падежа дополнения, в других – употребление винительного падежа, в третьих – наблюдается факультативное их использование.

[Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/2807/2060) (Розенталь Д.Э. и др. Справочник.)

Я бы сказал, что широко используется родительный падеж только в случаях 1.2, 1.3, 1.5 и 1.6, и даже в этих случаях в разговорной речи часто применяется винительный падеж.

Ваш пример - фразеологизм, пункт 1.6, т. о. падеж здесь - родительный.

Answer (score 3):

Хм. При отрицании действия, выраженного переходным глаголом, родительный падеж употребляется едва ли не чаще винительного. *Подать руку* / *не подать руки*, *взять деньги* / *не взять денег*, *услышать шум* / *не услышать шума*, *найти причину* / *не найти причины*, *поймать рыбу* / *не поймать рыбы* и т. д. Сомневаюсь, что для вас это новость, в чем же вопрос?

Comment: Этот факт оказался для меня _новостью_ :)) Раньше я никогда об этом не задумывался, а сейчас вижу, что родительный падеж в таких случаях употребляется чаще винительного.

Answer (score 1):

Это [фразеологизм](http://phraseology.academic.ru/7979/%D0%9D%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7):

> Не отвести глаз
>   от кого, от чего. Разг. Экспрес. О ком-либо или о чём-либо особенно привлекательном, ладном (таком, что залюбуешься).

Здесь именно множественное число, родительный падеж. В единственном числе это выражение становится нелепым. Сравните с выражением: "Работать не покладая рук".

Comment: Я нашел эту ссылку, но она ничего не объясняет на самом деле. Вопросы «от кого?», «от чего?», на мой взгляд относятся к последующему управлению: «…не можешь отвести **от него** глаз.»

Comment: наверно падеж должен определяться не формой слова а его ролью в предложении. тогда выходит что винительный.

Comment: @Aksakal Все-таки падеж определяется именно *формой слова*, а не его ролью в предложении.