# Why do you use "воды" in this sentence?

Tags: существительные

I just saw the following two sentences:

> У мальчиков есть вода.
>
> У мальчиков нет воды.

It seems that the meaning is something like *The children have water.* and *The children don't have water.*. However, why do the two sentences use different forms of `вода` or `воды`? (I don't know the proper form of those words, but maybe `вода` is the proper and `воды` is the plural form of it?) But then I'm not sure why the latter uses plural form...

What makes these two words different?

*By the way is there any good dictionary to list all the conjugated forms of a noun? I searched both `вода` and `воды` and then got results in both times, but I even can't see which is the proper form!*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Direct object of negated verbs takes which case?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2807/direct-object-of-negated-verbs-takes-which-case)

Comment: @jwalker While the result might have ended up as a duplicate, the reason I posted the question was just that I didn't know the negation rule to begin with. Thanks for the good reference though.

Comment: BTW. _Воды_ is also indeed the plural form of "вода" which coincides with singular genitive case except the accent (there are quite a few words sharing this pattern). Yet the usage of the plural form "воды" is somewhat limited just like English "waters" is.

Comment: @user4419802 thank you for the good follow-up. Yes that's why I suspected it at first.

Comment: Note where the stress is: "нет воды́" is singular genitive, while plural nominative is  "во́ды".

Comment: What is aqua (in English)? Why not "water"?

Comment: @Anixx Aqua is just a fancy word for water (It's the Latin word for water and we love to use Latin/Greek for technical terms or being fancy). You can ask English SE and they might be able to tell you more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the predicate word `есть`, 'there is', the noun is used in the Nominative case, that is in the dictionary form, but after the predicate word `нет`, 'there's no', the noun is used in the Genitive case, like the objects after other negative predicates.

The best dictionary to list all the conjugated forms of a noun is ABBYY Lingvo, but it cost some money, if you don't want to buy it, use Wiktionary, it lists all the case forms of most Russian words, [here they are](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0#.D0.A0.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9) for `вода`.

Comment: Thanks. I just started Russian 5 days ago and didn't know that the genitive case must be used after `нет`. As to the dictionary, thanks for the suggestion. I still search for the good English-Russian dictionary, but might end up with purchasing it.