# Accusative vs. Genitive Case after не иметь

Tags: грамматика

In **Отец не имеет прав на ребёнка.**, прав is in the genitive plural.

But in **Все имеют недостатки, но не все - способности.**, способности is in the accusative plural.

Why is this the case, when both follow иметь and не?

Comment: Related: [Direct object of negated verbs takes which case?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2807/direct-object-of-negated-verbs-takes-which-case)

Comment: In the second example negated is _все_, not _иметь_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, the case of noun may vary depending on the meaning of *иметь* (own, use, simply link-verb etc.). But in this particular case that's because of *negation*.

Consider, *Отец имеет права на ребёнка* (Accusative), but *Отец не имеет прав на ребёнка* (Genitive).

It's like this, because of the language history and incomplete replacement of Genitive by Accusative. The whole story is quite complicated and may confuse even native speakers, but for our example we may confine only to this: **не иметь** requires **Genitive case**.

You may find more following this link: [Какой падеж нужен при отрицании?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/67-otr)