# "Это вовсе не сводит на нет тот факт" or "того факта"

Tags: грамматика

What form should I use in this case, the form of Accusative Case or of Genitive?

> Это вовсе не сводит на нет **того факта/тот факт**, что они
>   преступники

Comment: Related: [Direct object of negated verbs takes which case?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2807/direct-object-of-negated-verbs-takes-which-case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Both* forms are possible here. The transitiveness of a verb doesn't mean it can never be used in genitive case (an obvious example: 'он этого факта не знает'). Depending on context, genitive (after a verb with negation) can even be preferable to accusative if otherwise it might be not completely clear, which noun or pronoun is in nominative case and which one is in the accusative at that. For example, the previous sentence gives another fact, opposed to the fact (next sentence) that some people 'are criminals':

> Эти двое спасли полицейскому жизнь. Это вовсе не сводит на нет тот
>   факт, что они преступники.

In case (1) the pronoun **это** is understood as being in accusative, the second sentence might mean the speaker *emphasizes* the first fact, which can't be completely beaten by the known second 'fact' (calls for mercy). In case (2) the noun **факт** is perceived as being in accusative, then the speaker just *reminds*: despite the first fact, they are still criminals. So, to make the first version clearer, the pronoun can be used in genitive:

> **Этого** вовсе не сводит на нет тот факт, что они преступники.

And vice versa - with different meaning:

> Это вовсе не сводит на нет **того факта**, что они преступники.

Style wise (to avoid double negation) it is possible to replace **не сводит на нет** with the more simple **не отменяет**, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The idiom **Сводить на нет** means *to reduce to zero (nothing) the successful results gained before due to improper actions. *Сводить* is a transitive verb which requires the noun in the **accusative**.

> Это вовсе не сводит на нет **тот факт**, что они преступники

The noun in the genitive is used after some verbs when the collocation bears a shade of uncertainty

> ждать (каких-то) писем, ждать (какого-то) поезда.

But if a noun is animate or bears a shade of certainty, then we use the accusative.

> жду одну девушку, жду московский поезд.

We have a definite факт, not какой‐нибудь.

Comment: But doesn't a transitive verb sometimes take on the genitive form? For example, ждать поезда.

Comment: Please, read the additional information

Comment: See also. a"related " comment  for more information

Comment: In fact, the "related" comment is more supportive of genitive form in this case as it is a negated-verb case.

Comment: Yes, the explanation is a bit vague, see "accusative " #1.

Comment: Why not  "genitive " #4? Not abstract enough?

Comment: Тот факт, что они преступники is not any fact. Read my explanation.

Comment: What about: "Они завтра будет сходка. Это мне известно из достоверных источников, хотя я и не знаю ещё точного времени" - It looks to me that saying "точного времени" here is more natural than "точное время", but the time here is definitely not just any time.

Comment: Abstract,  uncertain, точный doesn't add any information

Comment: You can drop точный from my example. The main point is that the speaker in it doesn't mean just any time, but the particular time of the gangsters' meeting, even though he doesn't know it yet.

Comment: First of all, a strict negation, then the verb знать, then an abstract noun. That's enough for the genitive.

Comment: What is ''strict negation''? Why does the verb знать matter? It is not on the list.

Answer (score 1):

Just some rules from new.gramota.ru.
Какой падеж нужен при отрицании?
Существительное, относящееся к глаголу с отрицанием, может иметь форму родительного или винительного падежа, например: *не прочитал этой статьи – не прочитал эту статью*. Трудность заключается в том, что в одних случаях тот или иной падеж является предпочтительным, а в других существует равная возможность употребления как родительного, так и винительного падежа.

Когда нужен **родительный** падеж?

При сочетании с глаголом **не иметь**:

> не имеет права, значения, смысла, намерения, понятия, влияния; не имеет дома, денег, машины, брата, друга, сведений.

При наличии слов **никакой, ничей, ни один**:

> не взял на себя никакой ответственности, не потерял ни одного грамма, не прочитал ни одной статьи.

При **глаголах восприятия, мысли**:

> не понял вопроса, не знал урока, не чувствовал боли, не заметил ошибки, не видел дорожного знака.

Если существительное имеет **отвлеченное значение**:

> не теряет времени, не испытывает желания, не скрывает радости.

Если в качестве зависимого слова используется **местоимение**:

> не допущу этого; не делайте того.

Если перед глаголом или непосредственно перед именем есть **усилительные частицы** и, даже:

> Отправлялись за покупками втроем, но Любе и слова сказать не удавалось, старики сами все выбирали (Кетл.); Руки дрожат и не держат даже плошки с лекарством - не удержать им и книги (Сарт.); На тротуарах тесно, но никто вас не толкнет, никто ни с кем не ссорится, не услышишь даже громкого слова (газ.)

При наличии **повторяющегося союза ни... ни**:

> не читает ни книг, ни газет.

В некоторых **устойчивых сочетаниях**:

> не играет роли, не производит впечатления, не обращает внимания, не уделяет внимания, не приносит ущерба, не придает значения, не вызывает сомнения, не принимает участия  и т. д. А также: не говоря (не сказав) худого слова; не сводить глаз с кого-чего-л.; не находить себе места; плетью обуха не перешибешь.

Когда нужен **винительный** падеж?

Если **отрицание не стоит не при глаголе**, а при другом слове:

> не очень люблю стихи, не всегда читает книги, не вполне усвоил предмет (ср.: люблю стихи, но не очень; читает книги, но не всегда; усвоил предмет, но не вполне).

Если при глаголе кроме данного существительного должно быть **еще одно зависимое существительное или прилагательное**:

> он не считает книгу интересной; не прочитал статью за вечер; не обеспечили регион электроэнергией; Разве вы не считаете эту практику полезной?

Если существительное относится **к инфинитиву, отделенному от глагола с отрицанием другим инфинитивом**:

> он не хочет начинать писать мемуары (ср. он не хочет писать мемуаров и мемуары).

При наличии в предложении местоимений, указывающих на **определенность** объекта:

> Эту песню не задушишь, не убьешь; он не решил эту задачу (ср.: он не решал задач); Ростов, не желая навязывать свое знакомство, не пошел в дом (Л. Толст.).

При наличии после существительного **придаточного предложения со словом который**:

> Он не прочитал книгу, которую я ему дал.

При **одушевленном существительном или при имени собственном**:

> Со времени моего кондукторства я не люблю Лесную улицу (Пауст.); Но Суровцев уже понимал, что уйти, не повидав Веру, не в силах (Чак.).

Если отрицание входит в состав частицы **едва не, чуть не, чуть-чуть не**:

> Едва не уронил стакан; Чуть не пропустил трамвай; Чуть было не потерял билет.

В **собственно отрицательных предложениях** типа Некому показать работу; негде опубликовать статью.

В некоторых **устойчивых сочетаниях**: Не морочь мне голову; Не скаль зубы.

В остальных случаях существительные в описываемых конструкциях обычно можно использовать в форме и родительного падежа, и винительного падежа.

Comment: What's the difference between new.gramota.ru and www.gramota.ru?