# Should words agree in case and number?

Tags: падежи, родительный-падеж, винительный-падеж

Here's a quote from Anna Karenina:

> Как это будет ему доказано, он не знал, но знал, что это, несомненно, логически будет ему доказано, и он ждал этого доказательства

I would like to know: why is `этого` in genitive case, singular form, and `доказательства` in accusative case, plural form? Shouldn't they agree in number?

Comment: this topic has been addressed several times in the past, please take a look  at [Why do some nouns take the genitive case instead of the accusative?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14855/why-do-some-nouns-take-the-genitive-case-instead-of-the-accusative)

Comment: ***доказательствА*** here is Genitive form of singular ***доказательство***, so it agrees with the pronoun ***этого***, in Accusative plural they would inflect as ***этИ доказательствА***

Comment: Why did you ask the same question on multiple sites at the same time? I see it at https://www.reddit.com/r/russian/comments/8pznvo/in_он_ждал_этого_доказательства_why_is_этого_in/. Just ask in one place, and if you do not get an answer after a day or two (not a minute or two) then ask elsewhere.

Comment: @KCd how can you dictate a person the way they should go about finding out an answer? it's their right to ask here regardless of their activities elsewhere, isn't it?

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка anyone can do whatever they want. I think, however, that posting the same question on multiple Q&A sites at *essentially the same time* without waiting to see what happens at one site first is not a good use of people's time. If a question is asked at site X and Y together then the OP may get an acceptable answer at X and ignore anything happening at Y since there is no longer interest after getting the answer at X.  I was writing in favoring of *waiting* a bit to see if a good answer is given at one site first, not never asking elsewhere.

Comment: @KCd to be on a safe side one may assume the OP needed the answer urgently, i personally don't mind them doing that, if i do hang out here i'm ready to waste some of my own time

Comment: word *доказательства* in singular form. слово *доказательства* в винительном падеже и единственном числе

Comment: @KCd the concept of abusive cross-posting is usually meant for different section of the same forum, thus being a spam-like activity, making the same people (dwellers of the forum) to see the same message again and again (entering one then another section of the forum to read different new messages). However when we talk about different forums - we imply different people dwelling here and there. And then x-posting does not mean "showing same message to same person 10 times" so much as "showing same message to 10 different persons" and then there is nothing wrong in x-posting.

Comment: It would be nice, though, if the x-poster would include links to alternative resources where he put the same exact questions, so curious and future readers would be able to read comments of more people by visiting all those places later.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a plural form of the accusative case; it's a singular form of the genitive case. Like 'нет кого\чего?' 'доказательства'. The plural form of the accusative case for this word is 'эти доказательства'.